# OpenCV memory usage

Tags: android, opencv, memory, memory-leaks

I develop the application based on recognition object using OpenCV 3.3.1. I use Android Studio 3.0. I am quite confused by how much the opencv native takes memory (about 500MB) but the garbage collector is working well. When garbage collector is engaged memory is dropped on 100MB but it grows back. I did notice this memory usage when my app had crashed on out of memory. Is this normal or should I be interested in this problem? Because of sometimes, the memory grows to 700MB that seems a lot to me. If I miss some answered question which is related to this, I do apologize.

Comment: I have the same problem on MSVC. OpenCV functions such as resize, absdiff and other are called clCreateContext, which create an OpenCL context and ate over 150MB for nothing. Maybe in your case, OpenCV makes some other preparation?